# Fedora 26 libvirt connection times out

Tags: virtualization, fedora, linux-kvm, qemu, libvirt

I've been trying to get `libvirtd` and `virt-manager` to work for days now.

I have all the entire "Virtualization" group of packages installed and have confirmed that `libvirtd` is running with `systemctl status libvirtd`.

When I open `virt-manager` (as root or a normal user), I get the following: [Virtual Manager Main Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20mJH.png), with [these connection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txG2A.png).

If I use `virsh` then connect to `qemu:///system`, I get the following:

```
Welcome to virsh, the virtualization interactive terminal.

Type:  'help' for help with commands
       'quit' to quit

virsh # connect qemu:///system
[...]
```

Where `[...]` is simply blank; there is no response or error of any sort.

I have verified that `/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock` exists as well.

As an added note, which may or may not be of importance, `libvirtd` always fails to shutdown when I shut the computer down, and I have to forcefully power the machine off.

What should I do to get virtualization working?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like libvirtd is stuck / hanging during initialization for some reason. It is hard to diagnose why from the info you provided, but I'd recommend filing a bug against 'libvirt' in the Fedora bug tracker. If you can capture a stack trace of libvirtd daemon that would help the maintainers diagnose the problem. eg use GDB to get stack trace

```
 $ dnf debuginfo-install libvirt
 $ pgrep libvirtd
 ...prints PID of libvirtd...
 $ gdb
 (gdb) attach $PID-OF-LIBVIRTD
 (gdb) thread apply all backtrace
```

Then add the output to the bug as an attachment